# react-admin: changing resource data in store without http request

Tags: react-admin

i need to modify resource data in store:

```
State->admin->resources->Orders->data
```

but without calling http request, like shown in documentation example:

```
// in src/comment/commentActions.js
import { UPDATE } from 'react-admin';
export const COMMENT_APPROVE = 'COMMENT_APPROVE';
export const commentApprove = (id, data, basePath) => ({
    type: COMMENT_APPROVE,
    payload: { id, data: { ...data, is_approved: true } },
    meta: { resource: 'comments', fetch: UPDATE },
});
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. However, as we usually handle optimistic behaviours and other niceties, it won't be straightforward.

If you need your action type for other things (such as sagas or custom reducers):

```
// in src/comment/commentActions.js
import { UPDATE, FETCH_END } from 'react-admin';

export const COMMENT_APPROVE = 'COMMENT_APPROVE';

export const commentApprove = (id, data, basePath) => ({
    type: COMMENT_APPROVE,
    payload: { id, data: { ...data, is_approved: true } },
    meta: { resource: 'comments', fetchResponse: UPDATE, fetchStatus: FETCH_END },
});
```

If you don't:

```
// in src/comment/commentActions.js
import { CRUD_UPDATE_OPTIMISTIC } from 'react-admin';

export const commentApprove = (id, data, basePath) => ({
    type: CRUD_UPDATE_OPTIMISTIC,
    payload: { id, data: { ...data, is_approved: true } },
    meta: { resource: 'comments' },
});
```