# react-admin: changing a list from store without http requests

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-admin, admin-on-rest

I am using [react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) and I need to control directly the store from one resource, in my case, the `orders` resource.

Everytime I run the `GET_LIST`it appends the new records in the list from the store, but, I would like to get a new list from the server and discard the old ones. Here`s where I retrieve the records:

```
    dataProvider(GET_LIST, 'orders', {
        filter: { updatedAt: filterDate }, // Get date from Filter.
        sort: { field: 'updatedAt', order: 'DESC' },
        pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 999 },
    }).then(response => response.data)
```

So, I decided to manipulate the store directly and after some digging I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229173/7948731) and this code from the source:

```
const dataReducer: Reducer<RecordSetWithDate> = (
    previousState = initialState,
    { payload, meta }
) => {
    if (meta && meta.optimistic) {
        if (meta.fetch === UPDATE) {
            const updatedRecord = {
                ...previousState[payload.id],
                ...payload.data,
            };
            return addRecords([updatedRecord], previousState);
        }
        if (meta.fetch === UPDATE_MANY) {
            const updatedRecords = payload.ids.map(id => ({
                ...previousState[id],
                ...payload.data,
            }));
            return addRecords(updatedRecords, previousState);
        }
        if (meta.fetch === DELETE) {
            return removeRecords([payload.id], previousState);
        }
        if (meta.fetch === DELETE_MANY) {
            return removeRecords(payload.ids, previousState);
        }
    }
    if (!meta || !meta.fetchResponse || meta.fetchStatus !== FETCH_END) {
        return previousState;
    }

    switch (meta.fetchResponse) {
        case GET_LIST:
        case GET_MANY:
        case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
            return addRecords(payload.data, previousState);
        case GET_ONE:
        case UPDATE:
        case CREATE:
            return addRecords([payload.data], previousState);
        default:
            return previousState;
    }
};
```

So, based on that, I created a custom action to delete the old ids from my list and add the new ones retrieved from the data source:

```
   import {GET_LIST, DELETE_MANY, FETCH_END } from 'react-admin';
    export const UPDATE_ORDER_ADMIN = 'UPDATE_ORDER_ADMIN';
    export const update_orders_admin = (data, oldIDS) => ({
        type: UPDATE_ORDER_ADMIN,
        payload: { data, ids: oldIDS },
        meta: {
            resource: 'orders',
            optimistic: true,
            fetch: DELETE_MANY,
            fetchResponse: GET_LIST,
            fetchStatus: FETCH_END,
        },
    });
```

And I am using this custom action after retrieve data from the backend:

```
   dataProvider(GET_LIST, 'orders', {
        filter: { updatedAt: filterDate }, // Get date from Filter.
        sort: { field: 'updatedAt', order: 'DESC' },
        pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 999 },
    }).then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => {
            const ids = orders ? Object.keys(orders) : [];
            update_orders_admin(data, ids);
            this.setState({ isLoading: false })
            return null;
        });
```

However, the system is calling the DELETE action from backend, trying to delete the records from the database, while, what I would like is just delete these records from my view.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom action you have the fetch set as **DELETE_MANY** which will do a loop over every id performing **DELETE** operation. Not sure if you implementation will work, but the current error is about that. You could try to remove the fetch ans see what happens, but I think without it he will not fetch records. If I'm not mistaken RA only adds new ids to data, however if data changed in the meantime I don't think it will replace the changed data for that you need to reimplement the data provider to change the update data behaviour which is similar to what you're trying.